# New Lenovo, Intel i7, 8GB of RAM, but high CPU usage, loud fan

Tags: laptop, memory, cpu, fan, intel-core-i7

I just ordered a NEW Lenovo G40 laptop with 8GB of RAM DDR3, and Intel Core i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40 GHz 2.40 GHz. It is acting very strange. The fan is always running. MUCH louder than my previous 5-year-old Dell laptop. It is especially annoying because when I even do something so simple as open a new tab in Chrome, the CPU usage shoots up to 75% and the fan gets louder. The memory usage is constantly at high levels (right now its at 67%). I would have expected that this thing (with i7 and 8GB of RAM) would have no issues like this -- ironically, the performance in use doesn't seem to be of any issue, i.e. I can run programs fine and they seem fast.. it's just that it acts and sounds like its being overworked like a whiny son of a ...

I feel like there is a setting somewhere that can solve these problems. Do you know how I can fix this? Your expertise will be GREATLY appreciated, and my heart and lungs will thank you for some more years on my life.

Answer (score 1):

Lenovo has a [Fan Speed Control Driver](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds008774) which you can download.

Other things to try:

- Ensure laptop is on a hard surface (table, desk counter, etc)
- See if there is a difference when running on battery vs plug-in (try removing battery)
- In Control Panel->Power Options, see if you can create a customized power plan

Answer (score 1):

For the insane CPU usage:

1. Open task manager.
2. Click on the tab called "Processes" (for windows 10, click on details).
3. Find out which programs are using a butt load of memory by clicking on the memory tab in the processes/details window. Everything will be organized by memory usage.
   3.Close tasks that you don't want running. Here are some things you can close:

-Installers

-Apple crapware like iTunesHelper and iPod service

-Synaptics TouchPad Enhancements

-hkcmd

-One drive (unless you use it of course)

Programs that use lots of memory also use more cpu than other programs.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering the same problems with my Dell Latitude E7250 with an i7-5600u and 8gb of ram.

It seems that this generation of Intel chips is extremely dependent on ram capacity. I also had the same problems with the fan going berserk for the simplest task....

I decided to add an extra 4gb of ram to the PC to bring it up to 12gb and now chrome isn't turning my PC into a windmill.

If you have an extra ram slot I would suggest you use that ram slot with an 8gb or 4gb stick.. nowadays an 8gb stick of ddr3 doesn't go for a lot so I don't believe that you'll have any problems solving the fan issue.

Comment: -1 because this doesn't make sense. Amount of RAM used doesn't depend on CPU it's paired with. Exactly as much RAM is used as the programs you're running request.

Comment: @gronostaj On the contrary, modern OSes use RAM compression, which is CPU-intensive. If something is causing high RAM usage, like Chrome, the CPU will be spooled up. Also, the answerer indicated it worked for them.. you're saying it didn't?

Comment: @Karu No, I'm saying it's not something specific to a particular generation of CPUs. RAM usage doesn't depend on CPU specs.